# Constructing $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ with a given zero level curve

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, closed-form, vector-fields, harmonic-functions

Let $C:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be a differentiable, simple, regular parametric curve with an unbounded image. I need to construct a differentiable at least almost everywhere function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ whose zero level set is the image of $C$.

Having almost no experience with vector calculus or differential geometry, I intend to do this by considering a vector field $p:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ where $p(x)$ is the normal vector to the curve at each point $x$ in the image set of $C$ and $\nabla f=p$.

How can I find, if possible, $p(x)$ at all $x \in\mathbb{R}^2$ not in the image set of $C$? I thought of, given that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is path-connected, finding $p$ by finding a solution to PDE $\text{curl}(p(x,y))=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the aforementioned constraint that for all $x$ on the image of $C$, $p(x)$ is the normal vector to the curve. If able to find a simple enough $p$, I would then recover $f$ from gradient field $p$ and pray that the image set of $C$ be some level curve of $f$.

For what curves can we end up with a closed-form expression for $f$? Are there other methods for finding a closed-form expression for $f$ given an expression for $C$?

Comment: What about $f(x) = \text{dist}(x, Im C)^2$? When $C$ has closed image then the zero set of $f$ should equal $Im C$ but I am not sure about the differentiability

Comment: A keypoint of the question is about having a closed-form expression. @Alex

Comment: Also, I think that this $f$ may be nondifferentiable at more than a countable number of points.

Comment: When you have an expression for $C$ then you might get one for this $f$ by solving the minimization problem

Comment: I think you are right. @FabrizzioMuzz Imagine that we are in a region where $C$ draws two parallel lines then consider the values of $f$ when we go from one line to the other one along the orthogonal direction, the middle point is a problem.

Comment: When you write 'differentiable almost everywhere' you mean away from a finite set or from a countable set or from a measure zero set?

Comment: I mean away from a countable set. It would be nice for $f$ to be differentiable everywhere, but I allowed some freedom just in case this may not be achievable in some cases. I am unsure if a curve with the conditions given in the post can always result in an $f$ that is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Hmm are there maybe any topological obstructions on the curves that one can get as a level set? For instance: Maybe when the image of a curve $C$ is the zero-set of a continuous function then it must have trivial isotopy (It is not knotted)?

Comment: At the very least $C$ has to be closed (and aribtrary curve isn't necessary so). Any closed set is set of zeroes of some smooth function (represent complement of $C$ as union of open balls, and sum bumps that are positive in the ball and zero outside).

Comment: @Alex What do you mean by "trivial isotopy"?

Comment: I edited the question just to make clear that $f$ can be differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @Alex for every closed set $E\subset\Bbb{R}^n$, one can find a $C^{\infty}$ function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $E$ is the $0$-level set of $f$; this is a standard exercise in analysis (playing around with bump functions etc). So, as long as the image of the curve is a closed set (which it will be for many of the nice curves out there), we can always find such an $f$. In fact this shows how ‘bad’/‘wild’ smooth functions or closed sets can be (if we don’t make any rank assumptions on the differential of $f$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Do you know what happens when we require $0$ to be a regular value of $f$?